# How to take user input in scheme and use it

Tags: scheme

I'm making a program in Scheme that needs to take user input in the form of numbers. It then uses these numbers to do basic comparisons and make decisions. I can find a number of lists of procedures, but I can't seem to figure out what to do.

I've used (read-char) and (peek-char) so far. They both return #\1 instead of a number. I tried to find a way to convert that, but can find nothing yet.

Comment: Could you post your code as well. See: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)

Comment: Have you tried casting the input via [`string->number`](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/guile/r5rs_56.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`read`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Reading.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._read%29%29):

```
(read)
```

> Reads and returns a single datum from in. If in has a handler associated to it via port-read-handler, then the handler is called. Otherwise, the default reader is used, as parameterized by the current-readtable parameter, as well as many other parameters.